# Error while importing pygraphviz in Spyder 3.3.6: not a valid Win32 application

Tags: anaconda, spyder, graphviz, pygraphviz

**Problem:**

I cannot import pygraphviz while running a python script in Spyder. The following code:

```
import pygraphviz
```

Gives the following error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

This behaviour happens only in Spyder. When running python from the command line, everything works fine.

**Possible solution direction:**

The error message seems to suggest that a 32 bit package is required. My python version (installed with Anaconda) is 64 bit, and if i look into pygraphviz the following code is generating the error:

```
import imp
imp.load_dynamic('_graphviz','C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\p3.6\\lib\\site-packages\\pygraphviz\\_graphviz.cp36-win_amd64.pyd')
```

Which seems to import a 64 bit package. If my understanding is correct, then for some reason when running from Spyder, a 32 bit package is expected. I don't know why, since i figure that if my Python version is 64 bit, my Spyder version would be as well since they are both installed by Anaconda. However, a possible solution could be to somehow use a 32 bit package, or get Spyder to work with 64 bit packages.

This is just my guess though, but i have no idea if my assumptions are correct so feel free to ignore this if it doesn't make any sense.

Thanks in advance!